# htaccess in subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

Once again facing the htaccess issue with subdomain.

The url for subdomain is http://m.domain.co.uk which redirects from http://www.domain.co.uk/m

Now the main site's index file is under  `/m/webstores/ecommerce/`.

In that index file the link for the product is `shopping-cart/293/test` where 293 is the product id and test is product name.

Now the htaccess code is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}   ^(www\.)?domain.co.uk/webstores/ecommerce/(.*)
RewriteRule  (.*)  http://m.domain.co.uk/%1  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/([^/]+)/?$ /shopping-cart/index.php?uiid=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

The htaccess file is located under  `/m/webstores/ecommerce/`.

The above code is detecting the subdomain correctly ie `http://m.domain.co.uk/webstores/ecommerce/` but not the product url.

Please suggest what's the wrong I am doing.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteRule  (.*)  http://m.domain.co.uk/%1  [R=301,L]`

should be

`RewriteRule  (.*)  http://m.domain.co.uk/$1  [R=301,L]`

$1 not %1 - you would be redirecting to `http://m.domain.co.uk/www.`